# Googles proprietary protocols in Android. Any info about them?

Tags: android

Is there any information available(or someone with the knowledge) regarding Googles proprietary protocols that's used in Android? I'm thinking about Google Sync and other Google apps/events where your device is communicating with Googles servers. I know that ActiveSync and XMPP is being used, but there are proprietary parts without much information. All knowledge about Googles proprietary protocols would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till this moment I know only about one post where one of these protocols is analyzed. Here are the links for the [first](http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2010/06/28/a-peek-inside-the-gtalkservice-connection/) and the [second](http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2010/06/25/remote-kill-and-install-on-google-android/) articles.